# Why is call to CDialog::OnShowWindow hanging my application?

Tags: c++, mfc

My application is hanging when a call to CDialog::OnShowWindow is made in my override of OnShowWindow. It only hangs when an editbox in the dialog currently has focus. It is hanging when both bShow and nStatus are 0 meaning the dialog is being hidden.

I have other similar dialogs and the call to CDialog::OnShowWindow() does not hang in them when an editbox has focus.

I'm really not sure how to debug this...

Comment: What does the debugger say it is doing during the hang? Surely it would be easier to diagnose if we had a stack crawl.

Comment: How do I give you a stack crawl? I see above the OnShowWindow call a DefWindowProcA call with int nMsg=24. Above that a bunch of user32.dll entries. Then above that a AfxWndProcBase, AfxWndProc calls, nMsg=135 in these entries.

Comment: That nMsg=135 is WM_GETDLGCODE apparently. Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set the DS_CONTROL style for the dialog. This fixes the infinite loop that was causing the hang.

These articles were of assistance:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/30/201988.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149501